# python async operation over list element

Tags: python

I have to iterate over a list and get some data. I have thought to make the loop async but I think it is not working.

```py
async def my_check_on_list_element(ele):
  code


a_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

for i in a_list:
  my_check_on_list_element(i)
```

I think I miss something, but I don't see what.

Comment: Please elaborate on what "It is not working" means. Is it not doing anything? Performing unexpected behavior? Causing nasal demons to fly out of your nose? Also, please provide a minimal working example that someone could copy/paste into their IDE and replicate your code's behavior. As written, I would get a NameError saying `code is not defined`.

Comment: you have to run your async function by asyncio.run or define new_event_loop

Answer (score 0):

```
import asyncio

a_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]


def process_the_list():
    for item in a_list:
        print(item)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_in_executor(None, process_the_list)
```